# Trigger Lambda Manually to read from SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, triggers, amazon-sqs

Is it possible to create a lambda which is triggered manually to read from an SQS.

I have an SQS queue which is constantly receiving messages, I want to process them when I want to (not continuous sync processing).

Can I have something like a start/stop lambda, where I start the lambda, and it consumes actively from SQS and when I stop it stops consuming

Comment: Can you describe your architecture better?  It doesn't sound like you're using SQS for it's intended purpose.  Yes, you can manually trigger it but I don't understand why you're using SQS and Lambda then.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, an AWS Lambda function is configured to "trigger" from an Amazon SQS queue. Whenever a message arrives, a Lambda function would be triggered.

However, instead of configuring a trigger, you could code an AWS Lambda function to call `ReceiveMessages()` on the queue itself. The Lambda function would then be responsible for calling `DeleteMessage()` after the message has been processed.

You can invoke a Lambda function at any time by using the `Invoke()` command.

The only decision you would need to make is whether the Lambda function should process:

- One **message** per invocation, *or*
- One **batch of messages** (up to 10) per invocation, *or*
- Run a loop that **keeps retrieving messages from the queue** until the queue is empty or until the Lambda function times-out (which could leave a message partially processed, so it isn't a good idea)